# Re-trying last item in stream, and continuing from there

Tags: dart, download, stream

I'm using a [library](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart) to download media. The [download function](https://github.com/Hexer10/youtube_explode_dart/blob/master/lib/src/reverse_engineering/youtube_http_client.dart#L76) returns a stream. Occasionally, partway through the download, an error occurs in one of the [http requests](https://github.com/Hexer10/youtube_explode_dart/blob/master/lib/src/reverse_engineering/youtube_http_client.dart#L92) used to yield each item of the stream.

When such an error occurs, I'm currently discarding the entire download and retrying from the beginning. Without being able to change the library's code, is it possible to retry the last item in the stream, so the http request can be retried again and the download can continue from there?

I realize this is probably impossible since the library's state would need to somehow be rewinded to before the error occurred. But maybe someone has a suggestion for how I can handle library errors like these that might happen many minutes into downloading a large file, and take advantage of the fact that I already have all the data successfully downloaded up to the point of the error.

Comment: not sure if this would work but check out [extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) in dart .

Comment: Extension methods would let me add new functions to the library, but they wouldn't help me modify the library's existing functions, right?

Comment: To some extent you will be able to modify, as a wrapper over existing functionality of that method. I haven't used them yet, so not much of experience. This [video](https://youtu.be/D3j0OSfT9ZI) gives a very quick overview.

Comment: Hmm. I still don't see how extensions would help me here. I'd need to change the internals of the streamInfo function to add retry functionality when one of its http requests fails. I don't think it's possible for an extension to override a function and change its behavior, right?

Comment: You are right, yes it wont actually modify the original method.

Comment: Will this package be helpful  [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) ? in the docs it is mentioned it can pause and also retry a failed download task.

Comment: Something like that may work, but this is a Dart server app, not Flutter